# Visual changes of the applications with root in Kubuntu 15.10/16.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 16.04, plasma, plasma-5

The problem is: when I start apps in Kubuntu with `sudo` or `kdesudo`, these apps change their visual themes and some of them are displayed with issues.

As an example:

Dolphin in normal mode:[image]

Dolphin with `kdesudo`:[image]

The next very strange thing is the output of Konsole, during `kdesudo`:

```
eugene@Eugene-KubuntuPC:~$ kdesudo dolphin
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
...
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
...
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
"ÐÑÐ¾ÑÐµÑÑ Ð¿ÑÐ¾ÑÐ¾ÐºÐ¾Ð»Ð° trash Ð½ÐµÐ¾Ð¶Ð¸Ð´Ð°Ð½Ð½Ð¾ Ð·Ð°Ð²ÐµÑÑÐ¸Ð»ÑÑ"
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
...
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::setOpacity: Painter not active
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::setOpacity: Painter not active
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::setOpacity: Painter not active
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
...
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::setOpacity: Painter not active
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::setOpacity: Painter not active
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
...
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
...
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
```

I tried to launch apps with enviroment variables such as `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`, but the result isn't much better:[image]

I noticed this problem in Kubuntu 15.10, but thought it would be fixed in LTS release. It seems I was wrong. How it can be fixed?

Comment: kdesudo bug: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=353263 . Comment #7 has a workaround: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=353263#c7